# Connecting Two Models and Only Displaying in Template When they have a relationship

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a site in Django where I have two models (players and seasons). I would like to display the players on a season page, but only when they are part of that season. Currently, this is what I have in my models file:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        name = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
        return name

class Season(models.Model):
    sid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    seasonname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #fsd is film start date
    fsd = models.DateField()
    #fed is film end date
    fed = models.DateField()
    #asd is air start date
    asd = models.DateField()
    #aed is air end date
    aed = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seasonname

class PxS(models.Model):
    # Do I need a primary key on this? PROBABLY -- One to many relationship: one player, potential multiple seaons
    pid = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    sid = models.ForeignKey('Season', on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    # position they finished in
    finishposition = models.IntegerField()
    # total number of players that season
    totalpositions = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        name = "Player: " + str(self.pid) + " | Season: " + str(self.sid)
        return name
```

Here is my views file for reference:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Player, Season, PxS

def home(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/home.html', {'seasons': seasons})

def player(request, pk):
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'webapp/player.html', {'player': player})

def season(request, pk):
    season = get_object_or_404(Season, pk=pk) 
    return render(
        request, 
        'webapp/season.html',
        {'season': season, 'players': Player.objects.all()}
    )

def seasons(request):
    seasons = Season.objects.order_by('sid')
    return render(request, 'webapp/seasons.html', {'seasons': seasons})
```

Currently, all players display on all season pages. I just can't figure out how to limit them. I've created a PxS model to link players with seasons based on foreign keys (pid and sid) but not sure how to implement them into the view. Am I missing something super obvious? Also, I believe it's a one to many relationship, because one player can be on multiple seasons. Is my thinking on this correct? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PxS is the through table in a many-to-many relationship. You should define that relationship explicitly:

```
class Season(models.Model):
    ...
    players = models.ManyToManyField('Player', through='PxS')
```

Now, in your `season` view, rather than sending all players explicitly to the template, you can just send the season; then when you iterate through seasons you can just use `s.players.all` to get the players for that season.

(Note, you shouldn't set primary keys explicitly unless you have a very good reason. Django automatically allocates an id field as the pk, so your PxS model *does* have one; the only thing you've done by defining the `sid` and `pid` pks explicitly is a) renaming them and b) disabling the autoincrement, which you certainly shouldn't do.)

Comment: This does it! Thank you so much.

Comment: New Question: Now that this relationship is established, how do I go about getting the seasons for each player? Do I need to do the same thing for the Player model or do I just need to reword the view now that the many to many relationship is established?

Comment: A many-to-many relationship works both ways automatically. See the docs on [accessing related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: I was missing the _set for the reverse relationship. Thanks again!